# Total length balanced cutting of associated array (like array_slice but for associated array)

Tags: php, arrays

Given associated array of messages (each 2nd level array is a result of different sql query):

```
$tmp = array(
    'type1'=>array ('key'=>'value'),
    'type2'=>array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3,4=>'men',5=>'pro'),
    'type3'=>array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3,'test'=>'website','creation'=>'www.prost.pro',8,9,10=>array('3dlevel','subarray'),11,12,13,14,15,16,18,18,19,20),
    'type4'=>array(1,2,3)
);
```

I need to display only 8 of them.
And they have to represent all and every types (1st level values) of messages.

So I need to call:

```
$total_quantity_limit = 8;
var_dump(array_assoc_truncate($tmp, $total_quantity_limit));
```

And to get something like:

```
array(
    'type1'=>array('key'=>'value'),
    'type2'=>array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3),
    'type3'=>array(1=>1,2=>2),
    'type4'=>array(1,2)
);
```

what have to be inside array_assoc_truncate()?

Comment: If this is populated by DB query, why not just limit the result set returned via the query? Also, if this is associative array (which does not guarantee order) how do you determine which values are to be truncated? I also have no clue as to why your data is structured like it is.  It seems you want to truncate certain elements from different subarrays in the main array, but the logic of how to do so, has not been made clear. It seem to me that your main issue is figuring out a better structure for representing your data (perhaps an object?)

Comment: @MikeBrant in php, assoc arrays are sorted, or else what is the point of ksort if the sorted order can't be guaranteed. AFAIK object methods/properties are not guaranteed.

Comment: how Object can help me? it has the same behavior here.

Comment: SQL limit: how to organize showing maximum possible quantity from EACH type? if I will use LIMIT -- it will take only first 8 messages, probably of one type. Right, I already has that data structure in app, it's inharitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example output I see, looks like you want something like:

```
<?php
$tmp = array(
    'type1'=>array('key'=>'value'),
    'type2'=>array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3,4=>'men',5=>'pro'),
    'type3'=>array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3,'test'=>'website','creation'=>'www.prost.pro',8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,18,19,20),
    'type4'=>array(1,2,3)
);

function array_assoc_truncate($array, $limit){
    $depth = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $out = array();

    //outter loop
    while($count < $limit){
        //boolean, was a key found
        $found = false;
        //loop through each top level key
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
            //if the value is an array
            if(is_array($v)){
                //get the keys
                $keys = array_keys($v);
                //if a keys exists at this depth
                if(isset($keys[$depth])){
                    //get the key
                    $key = $keys[$depth];
                    //if $out doesn't have the top level key yet, add it
                    if(!isset($out[$k])){
                        $out[$k]=array();
                    }
                    //set the value under $key in $out
                    $out[$k][$key]=$v[$key];
                    //increment our count
                    $count++;
                    //a key was found at this depth
                    $found=true;
                }
            }
            //if we hit our limit, break
            if($count >= $limit){
                break;
            }
        }
        //if no key was found at this depth, there is no more depth to search
        if(!$found){
            break;
        }
        //go down one more level
        $depth++;
    }
    //return the output array
    return $out;
}

echo '<hr><h1>Before:</h1>';
var_dump($tmp);
echo '<hr><h1>After:</h1>';
adump(array_assoc_truncate($tmp, 8));
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/a8cF5J

However, as hinted at above, if this is from the result of a query, you could/should probably restructure your query to give you better results.

Comment: I had spent several hours and could not achieve your result. But you did it.